# ¿Cómo guardar en 2 tablas usando entity framework?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo guardar en datos en 2 tablas, lo primero que debe hacer es guardar en la `tabla ticket` y luego debe guardar su archivo adjunto en la tabla llamada `Archivo` pero debe jalar el id de tabla ticket que es un identity.

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncar&#237;an.
↵Se termin&#243; la instrucci&#243;n.]
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2582782
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6033430
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +297
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady) +4291
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +91
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +446
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2698
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean&amp; usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1611
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +65
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +251
↵   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +43
↵   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
↵   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;Reader&gt;b__6_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +15
↵   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
↵   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +437
↵   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +167
↵   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +234
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +136
↵
↵[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +319
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;Update&gt;b__21_0(UpdateTranslator ut) +11
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +120
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +89
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&lt;SaveChangesToStore&gt;b__153_0() +11
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +292
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +163
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass148_0.&lt;SaveChangesInternal&gt;b__0() +21
↵   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +164
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +198
↵   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +7
↵   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +114
↵
↵[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
↵   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +200
↵   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +26
↵   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
↵   SoporteTicket.Controllers.TicketController.registrarTicket(Ticket ticket) in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\SoporteTicket\SoporteTicket\Controllers\TicketController.cs:87
↵   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +103
↵   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
↵   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
↵   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod&gt;b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive&gt;b__11_0() +50
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass11_1.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive&gt;b__2() +228
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_6.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__3() +35
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_1.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
↵   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
↵   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
↵   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
↵   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
↵   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
↵   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
↵   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9849413
↵   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
↵   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +163
↵</pre>                      </code>
↵
↵                  </td>
↵               </tr>
↵            </table>
↵
↵            <br>
↵
↵            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>
↵
↵            <b>Información de versión:</b>&nbsp;Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.8.4250.0
↵
↵            </font>
↵
↵    </body>
↵</html>
↵<!-- 
↵[SqlException]: Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncar&#237;an.
↵Se termin&#243; la instrucci&#243;n.
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
↵   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
↵   en System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<Reader>b__6_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
↵   en System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
↵[UpdateException]: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<>c.<Update>b__21_0(UpdateTranslator ut)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__153_0()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass148_0.<SaveChangesInternal>b__0()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
↵[DbUpdateException]: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
↵   en System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
↵   en SoporteTicket.Controllers.TicketController.registrarTicket(Ticket ticket) en C:\Users\USER\Desktop\SoporteTicket\SoporteTicket\Controllers\TicketController.cs:línea 87
↵   en lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
↵   en System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
↵   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
↵   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
↵-->
```

Método

```
[HttpPost]
            public JsonResult registrarTicket(Ticket ticket)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase filebase = Request.Files[0];
                    byte[] archivo;
                    var filename = filebase.FileName;
                    var extension = filebase.ContentType;
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filebase.InputStream))
                    {
                        archivo = br.ReadBytes(filebase.ContentLength);
                    }
    
                    ticket.Area = "Desarrollo";
                    ticket.Fecha_Reg = DateTime.Now;
                    ticket.codEstTicket = 1;
                    ticket.Flag_est = true;
                    context.Ticket.Add(ticket);
                    context.SaveChanges();
    
                    ArchivoTicket arc = new ArchivoTicket();
                    arc.Num_Ticket = ticket.Num_ticket;
                    arc.nombreArchivo = filename;
                    arc.archivo = archivo;
                    arc.contentType = extension;
                    context.ArchivoTicket.Add(arc);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                
    
                return Json(new { data = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Clases

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Num_ticket { get; set; }
        public string CodUsuario { get; set; }
        public string CodPerfil { get; set; }
        public string Nom_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Correo_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Telf_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Tit_problema { get; set; }
        public string Desc_problema { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Prioridad { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Reg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Mod_reg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_baja_reg { get; set; }
        public string Usu_asig { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Asig { get; set; }
        public string Usu_atencion { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Atencion { get; set; }
        public int codEstTicket { get; set; }
        public string Respuesta_atencion { get; set; }
        public Boolean Flag_est { get; set; }
    }

public class ArchivoTicket
    {
        public int CodArchivo { get; set; }
        public int Num_Ticket { get; set; }
        public string nombreArchivo { get; set; }
        public byte[] archivo { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public Boolean flag_est { get; set; }
        public string CodUsuarioCreacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaHoraCreacion { get; set; }
        public string CodUsuarioActualizacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaHoraActualizacion { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: intentaste guardar primero el ticket con SaveChanges antes de guardar el archivo?

Comment: hice eso primero y guarda el ticket pero no el archivo

Comment: pero vos estas usando una propiedad del ticket para guardar tu archivo, y seguramente EntityFramework todavia no te devolvio ese Id que necesitas.

Comment: Lo que deseo es obtener el id insertado para hacer el segundo insert, el problema es que no muestra a detalle el problema.

Comment: por eso, proba mover tu `context.SaveChanges();` antes de crear tu objeto Archivo. `ArchivoTicket arc = new ArchivoTicket();`'

Comment: Igualmente me envia ese error publicado.

Comment: y que error te da en la variable ex.Message? ese mismo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118537/discussion-between-darwin-and-ramiro-barone).